# Linking HIDs to physical input devices (Win API)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, hid

I am trying to make an application that blocks new input devices such as keyboards, mice, etc, unless the user manually allows them with existing input devices. I am writing it in C, using the Windows API, since cross-compatibility is not on my priority list right now.

The specifics are complicated, but I have made a simple program to do so in C. The problem with it is that an input device can register multiple HIDs. I am currently getting the HIDs using [GetRawInputDeviceList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getrawinputdevicelist) and their respective data using [GetRawInputDeviceInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getrawinputdeviceinfoa). Currently the program outputs all details I can find documented about the registered HIDs, but I am no closer to finding a way to link the HIDs to their physical device. For example, my keyboard registers two HIDs. Is there a way to do so using the current functions I have, or would I have to use a different set of functions from the Windows API?

Code: https://github.com/exeme-project/aks/blob/main/src/main.c

Example Output (One keyboard, two HIDs)

```
KEYBOARD \\?\HID#VID_145F&PID_02E2&MI_00#7&1e4f24cd&0&0000#{884b96c3-56ef-11d1-bc8c-00a0c91405dd}
Vendor ID: 81
Product ID: 0
Version Number: 1
Keyboard Mode: 1
Number of Function Keys: 12
Number of Indicators: 3
Number of Keys Total: 264
Type of Keyboard: 81
Sub-Type of Keyboard: 0
Usage Page: 12
Usage: 0

KEYBOARD \\?\HID#VID_145F&PID_02E2&MI_01&Col01#7&58818f5&0&0000#{884b96c3-56ef-11d1-bc8c-00a0c91405dd}
Vendor ID: 81
Product ID: 0
Version Number: 1
Keyboard Mode: 1
Number of Function Keys: 12
Number of Indicators: 3
Number of Keys Total: 120
Type of Keyboard: 81
Sub-Type of Keyboard: 0
Usage Page: 12
Usage: 0
```

Comment: If you have a keyboard and a pointing device on a USB hub, how would you decide whether that's two devices or a  single keyboard with built-in trackpad? Why would the software care?

Comment: Each device connected to a USB hub is treated as if it is directly plugged into the computer by Windows, and so has their own respective HID. The software cares because I want the user to be able to block all inputs, and so all HIDs, from any physical device.